# What is the difference between findById() and find<classname>ById()?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

In my spring data project, there is an entity that looks like:

```
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="category")
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="element_id")
    private Department department;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="agency_id")
    private Agency agency;

    public Employee() {}

    // routine getters and setters
}
```

In my EmployeeRepository, I find that I can derive a  method, findEmployeeById() that seems to work in exactly the same way as the usual findById() (but I'm not sure).  Can someone explain the difference between these two methods?

```
Optional<Employee> findEmployeeById (Integer id);
```

vs

```
Optional<Employee> findById (Integer id);
```

I "discovered" this by accident via autocomplete in my side (IntelliJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that while `findEmployeeById()` searches - as it states - employee by its field **named** `id`, `findById` searches by field **annotated** as `@Id` disregarding what is the name of the entity's id field.

In your case - as with many else's - the thing is that the `@Id` field happens to be named `id` so the result is the same.

Comment: Aha!  That make sense -- that's why they appeared to function identically.